# How can I bind a handler to the ended event for a video tag in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm having issues getting an ember view to respond to an "ended" view from a video tag - I set up a custom even in the application and created an ended method on the view, but no dice. I manged to get something working via $() in the view's didInsertElement but the standard "on" method of the view did nothing - it's like the event is happening on the element, but doesn't make it to the view. However setting via $ means "this" isn't bound to the view but to the element, which doesn't help me a ton

My view:

```
CommercialView: Em.View.extend
            tagName: 'video'
            templateName: "commercial"
            attributeBindings: ['autoplay', 'width', 'height']
            width: 320
            height: 240
            autoplay: true
            ended: (event) ->
                debugger
            didInsertElement: () ->
                #this.on('ended', this.ended)​ #doesn't work
                this.$().on('ended', this.ended) #shifts this to the element
```

My application:

```
App = Em.Application.create
    customEvents: {
        'ended':'ended'
    }
```

Comment: try adding an observer on "ended"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of jQuery, which Ember uses for events. It just can't delegate for video or audio events: http://jsfiddle.net/XzVXx/

Unfortunately it also lacks ability to take a `context` argument for events like it can for `$.ajax()`, so of coures you can't specify what `this` means.

The closest you'll get is:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
  this.$().on('ended', $.proxy( this.ended, this )) ;
}
```